# Add attribute in in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

How to write `$('label.someClass').attr('valid', true);` in Java Script with out using jQuery?

Comment: There is no `valid` attribute for `<label>` elements.

Comment: The selector part "$('label.someclass')" is kind of tricky, can you give the element an ID? Or are you trying to apply this attribute to all elements with a specified class? http://htmlcssjavascript.com/web/say-hello-to-javascripts-native-getelementsbyclassname/ this link could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all the `label` elements using `getElementsByTagName` which gives an array of matching elements. Run a loop on this array and check if the class name exists and set the attribute using `setAttribute` method.

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName){
}
else{
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
for(var i = 0;i<labels.length;i++){
    if(new RegExp("\\bsomeClass\\b", "g").test(labels[i].className)){
         labels[i].setAttribute('valid', true); 
    }
}
```

If the browser supports `getElementsByClassName` then we can use that conditionally.

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');
    for(var i = 0;i<elements.length;i++){
        ifelements[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'label'){
            elements[i].setAttribute('valid', true); 
    }
}
else{
    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for(var i = 0;i<labels.length;i++){
        if(new RegExp("\\bsomeClass\\b", "g").test(labels[i].className)){
            labels[i].setAttribute('valid', true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: And you've got a `,` where you should have a `;`

Comment: why not simply use `getElementsByClassName()`?

Comment: @Quentin - Fixed both of them.

Comment: @ajax333221 - Because it is not supported by all the classes. Though we can check for it and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('label.someClass'), function( label ) {
    label.setAttribute('someAttribute', 'someValue');
});
```

which implies that the browser is capable of ES5. An alternative for `.querySelectorAll` could be `.getElementsByClassName` too here.

Comment: please specify a reason for downvoting. If I made a mistake, help me and other guys out.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression to match the class:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
for(var i = 0;i<labels.length;i++){
    var classes = labels[i].className;
    if(classes && classes.match(/^(\s*|.*\s+)someClass(\s*|\s+.*)$/)){
         labels[i].setAttribute('valid', true); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myimage").setAttribute("src","another.gif")
```

[Try this Tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml)

Comment: The code in the question doesn't use an id to find the elements it is dealing with.

Comment: I don't have id, just a class on label element.;

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setAttribute()` method ([doc](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute)).

Comment: What about finding all the label elements which are members of the someClass class?

Comment: How to select label by class in pure Java Script?

Comment: In pure JavaScript? You can't. You need a DOM API. (OK, so I hate the term 'pure')

Comment: getElementsByClassName though you will want to check to make sure it is avalaible in all browser versions. You could have to loop through each and check to see if the type if a lable. OR you can use getelementsbytagname and loop through them to find the class.